# How do I publish on appexchange?

Tags: appexchange

I want to publish my app as free app on Salesforce AppExchange. I have already joined ISV partner portal through http://www.salesforce.com/partners/join/ and selected "AppExchange Partner Program". And I have read in salesforce packaging guide that for releasing the app I only need to register on partner portal which I had already done.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple more steps to go, but you're almost there, outline on the [Security Review](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Security_Review) page. Basically, once you're a partner, you need to run a security scan on your code, make it a managed package, upload a copy to the AppExchange, create and configure a publisher profile and a listing, click on the "Start Security Review" on the listing, and fill out the required information. Security reviews are generally 5-7 weeks waiting time, and there is no charge for free apps. The rest of the process besides the manual review should only take an hour or two of time.